# Can't get any test ad using AdMob on ios

Tags: ios, admob

I'm testing the AdMob. I do it like this:

```
AdManager *adManager = [AdManager sharedAdManager];
adManager.gadBannerView.adUnitID = @"a1514981c9444a4";
adManager.gadBannerView.rootViewController = self;
adManager.gadBannerView.delegate = self;
[adManager.gadBannerView setOriginY:self.view.frame.size.height-adManager.gadBannerView.frame.size.height];
[self.view addSubview:adManager.adBannerView];


GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"CECADC69-4A6B-4BB4-BF24-CACDA871B44A", nil];
[adManager.gadBannerView loadRequest:request];
```

And the @"CECAD..." the GAD_SIMULATOR_ID. I always get the error in the console when I'm testing on my simulator. Also same error when on my device. The iOS version is 6.0+. Even when I remove the `request.testDevices = ...`, I can't get any ad.

> "Google": To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, nil];

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason turn out to be I've not successfully loaded request and added the `GADBannerView` to my view hierarchy. And that log `To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, nil];` will always show. I think this should be tips to tell developer how to get test ads.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try

```
request.testing = YES;
```

Please note that you need to run in debug mode to get test ads. Actually I even do not use testDevices property and it works.

I think if you do not specify the test devices it get test ads on every devices, if you have compiled in debug mode.

Comment: I've tried your method but still no luck. I've checked it's indeed in debug mode.

Comment: thank you, you have helped me although you have not pointed out the real reason.

Comment: `request.testing` is deprecated. Don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

In the debug console you should see a message similar to this:

```
>     <Google> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ @"4d245710e0069eb2e3937c54e53e82c8" ];
```

Then you can set it in your code:

> self.adsView.adUnitID = adUnitId;
>   self.adsView.rootViewController =
>   self;
>   DFPRequest *request = [DFPRequest request];
>
> **request.testDevices = @[ @"4d245710e0069eb2e3937c54e53e82c8"];**
>
> [self.adsView loadRequest:request];